# ¿Qué es y para que se utiliza la instancia BindDictionary?

Tags: java, android

Quisiera que me ayudaran a entender mas sobre la instancia `BindDictionary` en *Android*,

- Para qué sirve y que es lo que hace.

  ```
  BindDictionary <Producto> dict = new BindDictionary <Producto> ();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`BindDictionary` es una de las dos clases principales de la biblioteca [Funadapter](http://amigold.github.io/FunDapter/). La otra clase es llamada como la misma biblioteca, `Fundapter`.

`BindDictionary` puede usarse para enlazar un ArrayList a un modelo de clase 
La clase BindDictionary se utiliza para enlazar los datos de una clase de modelo para un diseño (layout) personalizado.

¿Por qué necesitamos esto? Porque cuando se crea un `BaseAdapter` o un `ArrayAdapter`, es necesario reemplazar el método `getView` y en el método, se asigna cada atributo de una clase modelo a un widget correcto, por ejemplo, `TextView` o `ImageView`, en un diseño (layout) personalizado. Pues  `BindDictionary` es la clase para eso, pues usándolo ya no es necesario tener que implementar el método `getView`.

Este es un ejemplo de puesta en práctica de `BindDictionary`.
En él la clase modelo es `Product` y el diseño (layout) personalizado es `layout_product.xml`.

---

Cuando se quiere mostrar una lista de productos o algunos artículos en Android, se puede utilizar un `ListView`. Lo que tiene que hacer es crear una lista o `ArrayList` de nombres de productos. Algo así:

```
ArrayList<string> products = new ArrayList<string>();
products.add("Coke");
products.add("Pepsi");
products.add("Red Bull");
```

Y a continuación, se puede utilizar un `ArrayAdapter` para adaptar los datos:

```
ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(
this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
```

Suponiendo que haya creado en `ListView lvProduct` en su diseño, sólo tiene que hacer algo como esto para ver la lista de productos:

```
ListView lvProduct;
lvProduct = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvProduct);
lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**¡Echemos un vistazo más de cerca a la clase ArrayAdapter otra vez!**

Verás que se ha utilizado `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` para visualizar  la lista. Este diseño simple sólo puede mostrar un texto en una fila. ¿Qué pasa si desea mostrar los dos textos en una fila o para visualizar diseños complejos como el que se ve en Facebook o Twitter, que consiste en una imagen, una descripción, una serie de gustos, comentarios, etc botón para compartir? Sí se puede hacer eso mediante la creación de un adaptador a medida con un diseño personalizado. La mayoría de la gente prefiere BaseAdapter sobre ArrayAdapter bebido a que el BaseAdapter es mejor. Y sí, lo es.

Si se quiere una clase genérica que puede tomar una clase de lista / ArrayList de cualquier modelo y cualquier diseño personalizado, y finalmente mágicamente generar un adaptador para un ListView para mí, se puede usar esta biblioteca.

> Esto sería un mini tutorial de Funadapter

### I. Configurar Fundapter

Es necesario añadir la línea de código siguiente para sus dependencias de build.gradle (Módulo: app).

```
compile 'com.github.amigold.fundapter:library:1.0'
```

### II. Antes de la librería Fundapter

#### 1. Crear una clase modelo

First, you need to create a model class just as usual. It is a class that maps to attributes of a database table. Say you have a table tbl_product with 4 attributes (id, name, qty, price). So will create a model class like this: 
En primer lugar, es necesario crear una clase del modelo como de costumbre. Es una clase que se asigna a los atributos de una tabla de base de datos. Digamos que tiene una tabla con 4 atributos `tbl_product (id, name, qty, price)`.

Creamos una clase modelo así:

```
public class Product{
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public Integer qty;
    public Double price;
}
```

Usted es libre de hacer un setter / getter para cada atributo. Incluso una biblioteca de Google GSON que se utiliza para analizar el texto JSON, también hace los atributos públicos sin necesidad de utilizar los setters / getters.

#### 2. Crear un Custom Layout (diseño personalizado)

Es necesario un diseño personalizado para su artículo en un ListView. Supongamos un layout llamado `layout_product.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/tvName_layout_product" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:id="@+id/tvQty_layout_product"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName_layout_product"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Price"
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice_layout_product"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName_layout_product"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvName_layout_product"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvName_layout_product"
        android:layout_marginLeft="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

En el layout se crean 3 TextViews: `tvName_layout_product`, `tvQty_layout_product`, y `tvPrice_layout_product`. Esos nombres son importantes para la clase `BindDictionary` para asignarlos correctamente.

### III. Uso de FunDapter Library

Como ya se ha dicho, la librería `Fundapter` tiene dos clases principales: una es `BindDictionary` y la otra es `Fundapter`.

#### 1. Uso de `BindDictionary` para asignar un `ArrayList` a una clase modelo (Model Class)

Agregamos algunos datos en el  ArrayList products:

```
ArrayList products = new ArrayList();
Product p1 = new Product();
p1.id = 1;
p1.name = "Coke";
p1.qty = 20;
p1.price = 0.5;
products.add(p1);

Product p2 = new Product();
p2.id = 2;
p2.name = "Pepsi";
p2.qty = 15;
p2.price = 0.5;
products.add(p2);
```

**BindDictionary**

Una vez instanciado un objeto, por ejemplo `dict` desde `BindDictionary`, podemos luego usarlo para asignar cada propiedad, por ejemplo  `name`  a un widget correcto, por ejemplo `R.id.tvName_layout_product`.

Este es el código de `BindDictionary`:

```
BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();
dict.addStringField(R.id.tvName_layout_product,
        new StringExtractor<Product>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Product product, int i) {
                return product.name;
            }
        }
);
dict.addStringField(R.id.tvQty_layout_product,
        new StringExtractor<Product>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Product product, int i) {
                return product.qty.toString();
            }
        }
);
dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPrice_layout_product,
        new StringExtractor<Product>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Product product, int i) {
                return product.price.toString();
            }
        }
);
```

La clase `StringExtractor` es parte de la biblioteca. Y debido a que es una cadena, es necesario convertir el entero o doble a cadena antes de su regreso, como en este ejemplo, `return product.price.toString()`.

#### 2. Uso de `FunDapter` para crear un adaptador para un `ListView`

Ahora la parte divertida es utilizar `FunDapter`. Es tan simple como esto:

```
FunDapter adapter =new FunDapter(this, products, R.layout.layout_product, dict);
```

---

Enlaces:

- Este tutorial es una traducción de: [Android ListView Tutorial - FunDapter Class](http://kosalgeek.blogspot.com.es/2015/09/android-listview-tutorial-fundapter.html)
- [Biblioteca FunAdapter en Github](https://github.com/amigold/FunDapter)